# SpreadsheetGear formulas between WorkbookViews

Tags: wpf, formula, spreadsheetgear

I have 2 WorkbookViews:

```
<sprgr:WorkbookView Name="wbw1"/>
<sprgr:WorkbookView Name="wbw2"/>
```

How to insert formulas to a Worksheet in wbw2 that refer to cells in a Worksheet in wbw1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to creating cell references between [WorkbookView](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.WPF~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls.WorkbookView.html) objects is to ensure that both WorkbookViews share the same underlying [IWorkbookSet](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbookSet.html) object.  An IWorkbookSet is sort of analogous to a running instance of Excel, where you can have any number of workbooks opened within that instance, and you can create cross-workbook references.

So if all of your WorkbookView objects share the same [ActiveWorkbookSet](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.WPF~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls.WorkbookView~ActiveWorkbookSet.html), then creating cross-sheet or cross-workbook references should be as simple as entering an "=" sign in a cell in one WorkbookView and then clicking on a cell in the other WorkbookView.  You should find the appropriate reference is automatically created.  Example:

```
// Create a single workbook set containing two workbooks
IWorkbookSet wbs = Factory.GetWorkbookSet();
IWorkbook workbook1 = wbs.Workbooks.Add();  // Name = Book1
IWorkbook workbook2 = wbs.Workbooks.Add();  // Name = Book2

// Associate each workbook to a WorkbookView.  Because workbook1
// and workbook2 share the same underlying IWorkbookSet, wbw1 and wbw2
// now also share the same ActiveWorkbookSet, allowing for cross-workbook
// cell references
wbw1.ActiveWorkbook = workbook1;
wbw2.ActiveWorkbook = workbook2;

// Have user press "=" in a cell on one WorkbookView and then
// select a cell in the other WorkbookView.  This should result
// in a cross-workbook reference being created.

// Programmatically, you could just set a cell formula in wbw1
// to reference a cell in the other workbook.
wbw1.ActiveCell.Formula = "=[Book2]Sheet1!$A$1";
```